# How to deserialize a complex custom enum in Jackson without hand-rolling a JsonDeserializer?

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization

I have an enum with multiple custom attributes. I'm able to serialize it, and I've created a `@JsonCreator` method to deserialize it, but it's not working:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.*;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;

@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.OBJECT)
public enum SomeEnum {
    SOME_VALUE("Blah blah blah", "Example description");

    private final String displayName;
    private final String description;

    ScheduleOptimizationRuleCode(String displayName, String description) {
        this.displayName = displayName;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getCode() { return this.name(); }

    public String getDisplayName() {
        return displayName;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public static SomeEnum fromString(@JsonProperty("code") String value) {
         return SomeEnum.valueOf(value);
    }
}
```

When serializing, I get the following (correct) output:

```
{
  "code": "SOME_VALUE",
  "displayName": "Blah blah blah", 
  "description": "Example description"
}
```

When deserializing, my understanding was that Jackson would look in the object representation of my JSON string, dig out the `code` attribute, and pass in the code as a string to the `@JsonCreator` annotated method `fromString()`, but it doesn't work. `value` is always `null`.

I've also tried configuring the "mode" on the `@JsonCreator` annotation (e.g. `PROPERTIES`, `DELEGATING`), but it doesn't work. All the examples I've seen only have a single value, so don't have this issue.

I know I can hand-roll a `JsonDeserializer` and wire it in... and in the Jackson doc, but surely this isn't so complex that I need a hand-made deserializer...

How do I deserialize an enum with multiple attributes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found an [example of deserializing an enum](https://github.com/dmcwhorter/jackson-custom-enum-test), though only one of the two examples works. From looking at his enum I saw that he was passing in a `JsonNode`. Worked like a charm!

```
@JsonCreator
public static SomeEnum fromString(JsonNode json) {
     return SomeEnum.valueOf(json.get("code").asText());
}
```

Comment: Worked for me! In case `JsonNode` class is unknown, include `jackson-databind` in Maven dependencies (`pom.xml` file).